# Sample code from bq769x0 arduino library does not compile

Tags: arduino, battery

I try to use arduino library from github:
https://github.com/LibreSolar/bq769x0-arduino-library/blob/master/bq769x0.h
but it doesn't even compile.
Error is connected with :

```c++
#if BQ769X0_DEBUG
    void printRegisters(void);      
#endif
```

When I comment it it compiles, but I need this for debuging of course.
I assume, that this is a simple problem, but I have not much experience with programming. Please help.

I tried commenting it, and i think it works, but than i don't see any results in serial monitor

Comment: what error are you getting? you need to post the error the compiler is giving you

Answer (score 0):

This is called "conditional compilation". If the preprocessor value `BQ769X0_DEBUG` is defined, then the `bq769x0` class member function `printRegisters` is declared and defined (i.e. it exists). If `BQ769X0_DEBUG` is not defined, then that function does not exist and trying to call it is an error.

If you want to use that function, define it before including the header:

```c++
#define BQ769X0_DEBUG   // Enable debug features
#include <bq769x0.h>
bq769x0 BMS(bq76920, BMS_I2C_ADDRESS);
```

I'm fairly certain this will work on Arduino as AFAIK, it does not pre-compile libraries.

Note, that if you decide to disable the debug features by not defining it:

```c++
// #define BQ769X0_DEBUG
#include <bq769x0.h>
bq769x0 BMS(bq76920, BMS_I2C_ADDRESS);
// BMS.printRegisters does not exist!
```

it will be an error to later call that function. To fix that, you can use code guards in your code:

```c++
void loop()
{
  BMS.update();  // should be called at least every 250 ms
#ifdef BQ769X0_DEBUG
  BMS.printRegisters();
#endif
}
```

Another option would be to change the library header from:

```c++
#if BQ769X0_DEBUG
    void printRegisters(void);      
#endif
```

to

```c++
#if BQ769X0_DEBUG
    void printRegisters(void);
#else
    void printRegisters(void) {}
#endif
```

In this case, when `BQ769X0_DEBUG` is not defined, the `printRegisters` function is created but does not do anything. Calling it won't cause an error.

Or, make your own macro:

```c++
#ifdef BQ769X0_DEBUG
#define PRINT_REGISTERS BMS.printRegisters()
#else
#define PRINT_REGISTERS
#endif
```

Then change the usage to:

```c++
void loop()
{
  BMS.update();  // should be called at least every 250 ms
  PRINT_REGISTERS;
}
```

Note: this macro is hardcoded to use the `BMS` object. It would need to be modified to use others.